# ¿Cómo puedo crear una función que elimine todos los elementos de una clase?

Tags: javascript

Me gustaría crear una función en JS, la cual está vinculada a un botón y esta sea capaz de eliminar todos los elementos de una misma clase. Por aquí dejo lo que he intentado, aunque no funciona. Primero dejo el código

```
<button onclick="resetCapa()">Resetear capas</button></br>
```

Aquí dejo el de la función *`resetCapa()`*

```
function resetCapa() {
    document.getElementByClassName("caja").classList.toggle("hide");
}
```

Comment: Eliminar o solo ocultar?

Comment: A ser posible eliminar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu código veo esto:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("caja").classList.toggle("hide");
```

Recuerda que `getElementsByClassName` te da un `HTMLCollection`, por lo cual debes especificar el índice

```
document.getElementsByClassName("caja")[0].classList.toggle("hide");
```

---

Puedes hacerlo con [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), este método nos da una lista de nodos que podremos recorrer con [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
function resetCapa() {
  const elems = section.querySelectorAll("*");
  elems.forEach(el => {
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="section">
  <p>Hello world</p>
  <p>Hello world</p>
  <p>Hello world</p>
  <p>Hello world</p>
</div>
<button onclick="resetCapa()">Resetear capas</button></br>
```

Comment: Ninguna de las 2 funciona. En el primer caso me aparece este error: funciones.js:74 Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByClassName is not a function
    at resetCapa (VM93 funciones.js:74)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (principal.html:14)

Comment: @Guillemj entonces nos falta mas datos a tu pregunta

Comment: El caso es que tengo un botón que crea x div dentro de otro div. Lo que estoy preguntando es una función que borre todos los div creados con ese botón, los cuales se encuentran en el div con id = "section"

Comment: @Guillemj Nos faltaba el dato del `id` para reproducir el problema, debería funcionar ahora